# Understanding the meaning of「こちらにとって、近い間合い、相手にとって遠い間合いになっている考えていい」

Tags: meaning, translation

Currently I am translating a kendo book from Japanese. While I understand the general meaning, I was having trouble translating this sentence:

> こちらにとって、近い間合い、相手にとって遠い間合いになっていると考えていい

The closest I got is:

> For this way, it can be thought to be beneficial (good) if your maai (distance) gets closer, while for the opponent's maai gets farther.

What does kochira ni totte mean in this context?

Here is the full sentence:

> 写真のように相手が重心を後ろに下げたことが確認できたら、こちらにとって、近い間合い、相手にとって遠い間合いになっていると考えていい

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sentence needs と like 遠い間合いになっていると考えていい.

こちらにとって means 自分(自分達)にとって. However it implies "you" in this context because the author must write this sentence for the readers. I translate it as "You may think that it is close distance for you and far distance for your opponent".